# How to handle implementing different APIs for older and newer Android versions?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-camera

I am writing an app, which uses the older camera API for older android versions and the new camera2/torch API for API 23 and up.
Basically I determine once if the device is running a new enough Android version, and then switch between the implementations according to that. It boils down to this:

```
private static final int SDK_VERSION = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

private boolean isSdkVersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo(final int sdk) {
    return SDK_VERSION >= sdk;
}

if (marshmallowOrNewer) { //isSdkVersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo(23);
                            try {
                                cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0], true);
                            } catch (final CameraAccessException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } else {
                            cameraParameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                            camera.setParameters(cameraParameters);
                            camera.startPreview();
                        }
```

Upon running on Gingerbread I get a force close: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 java.lang.VerifyError
in this line:

```
 toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

which opens up the OnClickListener which contains above code and indicates that an API method is not supported in this version of android, which makes sense, but I'm not actually calling it here. How should I handle this situation properly, implementing different APIs for different Android versions, or how do I bypass this veryfication?

Stacktrace:

```
04-02 13:42:54.413 3815-3815/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 java.lang.VerifyError: t.t.t.MainActivity$1
                                                     at t.t.t.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace.

Comment: Your problem isn't in calling a method. AFAIK, it's in some interface or superclass of `t.t.t.MainActivity$1`. You are *sure* that `t.t.t.MainActivity$1` is the `View.OnClickListener()`? Do you have any other anonymous inner classes in the vicinity? `View.OnClickListener` has been around since API Level 1, so that would not seem to be the source of the `VerifyError`.

Comment: Line 61 is the OnClickListener and its the only anonymous inner class in MainActivity, which is the only class in my code.

I also found this in my logkitty:
04-02 13:42:54.413 3815-3815/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.getCameraIdList, referenced from method t.t.t.MainActivity$1.onClick

Comment: "Could not find method android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.getCameraIdList, referenced from method t.t.t.MainActivity$1.onClick" -- OK, that would seem to be your problem. Could you post this `OnClickListener`?

Comment: Samgak's answer helped. Appearently I mustn't have any references to an unsupported API on old android versions. Moving them to a different class fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered this problem when adding Camera2 functionality to my app. I can't speak authoritatively about the underlying mechanism because I only fixed it through trial and error, but through testing I found that the problem only happens on devices earlier than Ice Cream Sandwich or so, after that it's possible to avoid it by doing run-time tests for the SDK version like you are doing. It seems that for ICS and later, it's okay to use an unsupported API in your class, as long as you never call it, but earlier than that you need to make sure you never instantiate a class that uses an unsupported API call, whether you call it or not.

I fixed the problem with this method:

- Create a `Camera2Object` class (name it whatever you want) that calls the Camera2 API functions that you use. Remove all imports of Lollipop+ Camera2 classes from all other classes. It's ok to have a reference to this `Camera2Object` class in your other classes.
- Only create an instance of this class after checking that the API version is >= 21 (Lollipop), or Marshmallow in your case.
- In the class where you are currently calling the Camera2 functions inside an API version check if statement, change your code to check if your Camera2Object is not null and if so call a method on it that implements the functionality you had inside your if statement.

You might need to be a bit clever and rearrange your code so that all the Camera2 stuff is hidden inside this class - you might need to translate return codes etc into something that isn't dependent on Camera2 imports, and possibly return ints or Strings as references to Camera2 objects instead that get translated back and forth at the boundary between this class and the rest of your app.

You can have more than one class that calls Camera2 functions, as long as none of them are ever instances if the API version is less than 21.

This is tested on a 2.3.3 device, I can't vouch for earlier versions of Gingerbread. I also can't guarantee that you won't need to do this for ICS and after.

Comment: Whaaat that's pretty freaky. I will try.

Comment: Believe it, I can not.
Thanks, mate, this fixed it.

Comment: Wow, you are fast! It took me the best part of an afternoon to refactor my code like this. Glad to have helped